# Javascript object problems in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to render a map using d3 using an HTML page that runs on a django web framework. This is an example of the map directly from d3's example archives: http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312

I noticed that the states' low, high, average, and colors are all generated randomly using this function (that I commented out):

```
// var sampleData ={};  /* Sample random data. */   
// ["HI", "AK", "FL", "SC", "GA", "AL", "NC", "TN", "RI", "CT", "MA",
// "ME", "NH", "VT", "NY", "NJ", "PA", "DE", "MD", "WV", "KY", "OH", 
// "MI", "WY", "MT", "ID", "WA", "DC", "TX", "CA", "AZ", "NV", "UT", 
// "CO", "NM", "OR", "ND", "SD", "NE", "IA", "MS", "IN", "IL", "MN", 
// "WI", "MO", "AR", "OK", "KS", "LS", "VA"]
//  .forEach(function(d){ 
//      var low=Math.round(100*Math.random()), 
//          mid=Math.round(100*Math.random()), 
//          high=Math.round(100*Math.random());
//      sampleData[d]={low:d3.min([low,mid,high]), 
// high:d3.max([low,mid,high]), 
//              avg:Math.round((low+mid+high)/3), 
// color:d3.interpolate("#ffffcc", "#800026")(low/100)}; 
//  });
```

When `sampleData` is console logged in the broswer, it prints a dictionary of objects, when expanded, look like:

```
{"HI":{low:20, high:10, avg:15, color:'#ffffcc'}, "AK"....
```

When I replace the variable `sampleData` with my own data:

```
var sampleData= {
    "HI":{low:69, color:"#e6e6ff"},
    "AK":{low:84, color:"#e6e6ff"},
    "FL":{low:1099, color:"#0000ff"},
    "SC":{low:223, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "GA":{low:614, color:"#8080ff"},
    "AL":{low:228, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "NC":{low:686, color:"#8080ff"},
    "TN":{low:416, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "RI":{low:119, color:"#ccccff"},
    "CT":{low:319, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "MA":{low:1195, color:"#0000ff"},
    "ME":{low:128, color:"#ccccff"},
    "NH":{low:225, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "VT":{low:163, color:"#ccccff"},
    "NY":{low:1779, color:"#0000b3"},
    "NJ":{low:550, color:"#8080ff"},
    "AZ":{low:537, color:"#8080ff"},
    "AR":{low:222, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "CA":{low:3453, color:"#000066"},
    "DE":{low:84, color:"#e6e6ff"},
    "ID":{low:155, color:"#ccccff"},
    "IL":{low:1082, color:"#0000ff"},
    "IN":{low:452, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "IA":{low:219, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "KS":{low:197, color:"#ccccff"},
    "KY":{low:274, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "LA":{low:274, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "MD":{low:662, color:"#8080ff"},
    "MI":{low:894, color:"#8080ff"},
    "MN":{low:670, color:"#8080ff"},
    "MS":{low:82, color:"#e6e6ff"},
    "MO":{low:509, color:"#8080ff"},
    "MT":{low:72, color:"#e6e6ff"},
    "NE":{low:165, color:"#ccccff"},
    "NV":{low:206, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "NM":{low:213, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "ND":{low:46, color:"#e6e6ff"},
    "OH":{low:941, color:"#8080ff"},
    "OK":{low:215, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "OR":{low:1152, color:"#0000ff"},
    "PA":{low:1171, color:"#0000ff"},
    "SD":{low:43, color:"#e6e6ff"},
    "TX":{low:1490, color:"#0000ff"},
    "UT":{low:270, color:"#b3b3ff"},
    "VA":{low:723, color:"#8080ff"},
    "WA":{low:1667, color:"#0000b3"},
    "WV":{low:83, color:"#e6e6ff"},
    "WI":{low:541, color:"#8080ff"},
    "WY":{low:44, color:"#e6e6ff"},
    };`
```

I only get certain sections of my map filled in with the hex colors.
[image: Screenshot of results. Some states filled in, but not all.]

And my browser's console returns an error that doesn't happen when using the original `sampleData` which is:

```
uStates.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined
at SVGPathElement.<anonymous> (uStates.js:72)
at SVGPathElement.u (d3.v3.min.js:1)
at d3.v3.min.js:3
at Y (d3.v3.min.js:1)
at Array.Co.each (d3.v3.min.js:3)
at Array.Co.style (d3.v3.min.js:3)
at Object.uStates.draw (uStates.js:72)
at (index):136
```

In addition to this, the little tooltip that appears when the original `sampleData` is used does not appear when my custom `sampleData` variable is used. I'm wondering why that is. Here's the Javascript code for that:

```
function tooltipHtml(n, d){ /* function to create html content string in 
tooltip div. */
    return "<h4>"+n+"</h4><table>"+
        "<tr><td>number:</td><td>"+(d.low)+"</td></tr>"+
        "</table>";
}
```

Can anyone tell me:

1. Why I am getting that specific error in my console?
2. Why only *some* states are getting filled in with the hex provided in the object next to the state abbreviated string?
3. Why the tooltip doesn't work for my `sampleData`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between your two datasets of U.S. states: `uStatePaths` from the file `uStates.js` contains 50 states whereas `sampleData` contains only 48 states, the missing ones being Colorado and Louisiana. When the execution starts the first states get their `fill` values set, but the execution will stop once the first state is reached where no matching state is found in `sampleData` which throws the error you witnessed. The same problem causes your tooltips to not work as expected.

If the mismatch is just by accident, you can easily fix this by filling the missing states in `sampleData`. If this was done on purpose, you could avoid the error by introducing safeguards to your code in `uStates.js` checking for the existence of `data[d.id]` before accessing its properties.

Have a look at this [working fork](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/f88ca157c79d1493490a32bd9d71d9e5) of the code. The code uses the above mentioned checks and colors all non-matching states in red:

```
.style("fill",function(d){ return data[d.id] ? data[d.id].color : "red" ; })
```